# estimate Integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to estimate the following integral and then prove that the integral goes to zero if $Re(z_{1,2}) \rightarrow \infty$ :

$s\in \mathbb{C}$ $ Re(s)>1$:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma_{1,2}} \frac{(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z-1}dz
\end{align*} where $\gamma_1$ is a straight line parallel to the imaginary axis between to points $z_1=a_1+ib_1$ and $w_1=a_1+id_1$ and $a_1,b_1,d_1 > 0$
$\gamma_2$ is a straight line parallel to the imaginary axis between two points $z_2=a_2+ib_2$ and $w=a_2+id_2$ and $a_2 > 0$ and $b_2,d_2 < 0$

Thanks in advance !

Comment: So necessarily, $a_1=c_1$ and $a_2=c_2$. I wonder why the notation does not reflect this?

Comment: yes indeed... I will adadapt it

Comment: There it is !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just estimate the numerator and denominator separately. For the latter, use
$$\lvert e^z-1\rvert\ge\lvert e^z\rvert-1=e^{\operatorname{Re}z}-1,$$
and for the former)
$$\lvert(-z)^{s-1}\rvert=\lvert e^{(s-1)\ln(-z)}\rvert=e^{\operatorname{Re}((s-1)\ln(-z))}
 \le e^{\lvert(s-1)\ln(-z)\rvert}=e^{\lvert s-1\rvert\sqrt{(\ln \lvert z\rvert)^2+(\arg (-z))^2}}.$$
The last bit is probably easier to handle if you use $\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\le u+v$ when $u,v\ge0$, so that $$\sqrt{(\ln \lvert z\rvert)^2+(\arg (-z))^2}\le\bigl|\ln\lvert z\lvert\bigr|+\lvert\arg(-z)\rvert, $$
and hence
$$\lvert(-z)^{s-1}\rvert\le\lvert z\rvert^{\lvert s-1\rvert}\cdot e^{\lvert(s-1)\arg(-z)\rvert}.$$
Each factor on the right should be easy to control, and they're still swamped by $e^{\operatorname{Re}z}.$

Both integrals can be treated the same, but for the second one, you should choose a branch cut for $\ln(-z)$ along the negative real axis, hence along the positive real axis for the logarithm.

Anyhow, $e^{\operatorname{Re z}}$ will grow large much faster than $\lvert z\vert^{s-1}$, so the necessary estimates should be quite straightforward. I am leaving the details to you, or to other contributors if they feel like it. But notice that $e^{\operatorname{Re z}}$ is constant on your paths, and $\lvert z\rvert$ has its maximum and minimum at the end points, or where the path crosses the real axis.

Comment: Thanks ! Unfortunately $s$ is complex with $Re(s) > 1$. I forgot to mention that

Comment: I edited it for complex $s$. The resulting estimates are kind of rough, but should be more than plenty for the desired convergence result.

Comment: Ok I see that in fact the important argument is the fact that $e^{Re z}$ beats everything :-)